# Disable creation of report.txt while using Google Closure Compiler with Grunt JS

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler, gruntjs

To minify and obfuscate my JS code I'm trying to use Grunt's [closure-compiler](https://github.com/gmarty/grunt-closure-compiler) plugin.

I'm perfectly happy with the result, but after running Grunt I get `project.min.js.report.txt` file in the output directory. I haven't found any [options](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref?hl=ru#req) responsible for that.

The only solution I see is to create another task to remove the file. Are there simplier ways to avoid this file from reappearing?

Here is my gruntfile.js contents:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        "concat": {
            js: {
                src: [
                    "js/project.js"
                ],
                dest: "js/project.all.js"
            }
        },
        "closure-compiler": {
            frontend: {
                closurePath: "path/to/gcc_jar_directory",
                js: "js/project.all.js",
                jsOutputFile: "js/project.min.js",
                maxBuffer: 500,
                options: {
                    compilation_level: "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS",
                    language_in: "ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT",
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ["js/project.js"],
                tasks: ["concat:js", "closure-compiler"]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-concat");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-closure-compiler");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["concat:js", "closure-compiler", "watch"]);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible now using the `noreport` option ([read more](https://github.com/gmarty/grunt-closure-compiler#minification-report)):

```
'closure-compiler': {
    frontend: {
        closurePath: '/var/www/closure/',
        js: 'js/file.js',
        jsOutputFile: 'js/dist/file.min.js',
        maxBuffer: 500,
        options: {
            compilation_level: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
            noreport: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't as it's currently [hard-coded](https://github.com/gmarty/grunt-closure-compiler/issues/18).

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, but it's just this [Grunt plugin's issue](https://github.com/gmarty/grunt-closure-compiler/blob/master/tasks/closure-compiler.js), not Google Closure Compiler.

Created an issue for that.